# How to route browser traffic through an OpenVPN connection on Linux?

Tags: linux, proxy, openvpn, socks

I have set up an OpenVPN connection but I don't want to send all the traffic through it.

My current routing table looks like this:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.88.1 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp metric 100
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2
192.168.88.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.88.29 metric 100
```

The objective is to route all the traffic of a *specific* program through `tun0`, and the first candidate program is of course - a browser.

Do you folks have some ideas how it can be done?

---

I know about **iptables** source routing based on PID, but it would require recreating iptables rules every time a new process gets spawned. And since every tab of a browser is a new process... I honestly cannot imagine how it all can be done.

The next thought is to use local socks proxy and then run say `google-chrome --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"`.

This works fine with SSH-tunnels as `ssh` can act as a SOCKS-proxy. However, I didn't find a proxy program that can work the same way but without SSH-tunnel: i.e. expose SOCKS interface and route all traffic via `tun0`. Could you recommend something?

Comment: Please tell us what you want to do. Any program that talks to a server or specific port can be used by a SNAT or route to do what you want. If you have control over the other end, you can install Squid, ziproxy, or any small proxy for Web use. You can also use apt-get "dante-server" or "tsocks". Then use 10.8.0.1 as the destination, as well as the port configured, such as 1080, 3128, 8080 or whatever has been set. ;)

Comment: Hi @djdomi! Sorry for the late response. My goal is to run any program via `tun0` yet not having it as the default route. I liked the approach with `ip netns` suggested by @symcbean, but I'm yet to come up with a proper system configuration: the learning curve is sort of steep! :)

Comment: You need to read [ask]. Is it a specific target, such as an IP address, that this top-secret application with no name hits? We need more input ;)

Comment: @djdomi I know how to ask, thank you. I was looking for a solution for _any_ app.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even a random app has a destination every time it hits. This destination can be affected by the intervention, but we need to know this in order to help you further.

Comment: @djdomi I feel helped already :) Below go two suggestions that actually don't depend on app specifics: 1) using network namespace 2) using UID in iptalbes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use iproute2 and uid of the user that run browser or whatever.
For example:

```
ip route add table 502 default dev tun0
lp rule add uidrange 1000-1002 table 502
```

Comment: This is interesting approach, I didn't think about it. However I doubt it's gonna be convenient to work under two different users at the same time. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Run the programs you want to route via the VPN in a new network namespace with the tunnel as the default gateway.

You might want to reconfigure your PC such that the .desktop file for the browser (and any other program which should use the VPN) runs a script to control the behaviour and add a script to your openvpn config to set up the namespace.

Comment: Already reading about network namespaces! Thanks.

Comment: I'm still working on the configuration and I think about  running my VPN connection _inside_ the namespace. This way I can let it create the default route.